# Refactoring logic outside of Context.Consumer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To get my desired behavior I ended up nesting ternarys inside of my Context.Consumer and it looks pretty ugly.
I have tried refactoring out some of the logic, but I have been unable to get rerenders to trigger when the props/state change unless I use Context.Consumer.

Working on an app for a project. It uses SWAPI to search for pretty much anything in the Star Wars universe. I have a  that changes depending on the user's input, and then loads the results of their search.

I started out just trying to get the results to render after the fetch finished and was having some issues of handling the props/state update of the component not triggering a re-render. We recently learned about React's Context api so I decided to try using that in this simple project even though it's 100% not necessary. I did some reading and ended up with the Context.Consumer. It works great for what I want, and triggers re-renders when I need it to.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Consumer>
// value here is: characterData: this.state.characterData from App.js
// characterData is in App.js' state and is updated after the fetch is successful.
        {value => (
          <section className="results-container" style={this.styles}>
            {/* FIX refactor this \/ */}
{/* 
If they haven't searched for anything, characterData doesn't exist yet,
well it's an empty {object} so it renders the 'Enter a name and hit submit!'
If they search and the results are empty, it tells them to try another name.
If the search works it renders the results.
*/}
            {value.characterData.results ? (
              value.characterData.results.length > 0 ? (
                value.characterData.results.map(item => (
                  <p style={this.styles} key={item.url} className={item.index}>
                    {item.name ? item.name : item.title}
                  </p>
                ))
              ) : (
                <span>Coulnd't find anything! Try another name or topic.</span>
              )
            ) : (
              <span className="default-results-text">
                Enter a name and hit submit!
              </span>
            )}
            {/* FIX refactor this /\ */}
          </section>
        )}
      </AppContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
```

I am not getting any errors, just trying to figure out a way to clean this up.
When trying to move logic outside the Context.Consumer I have to fall back to using state/props and then it never rerenders.
I've tried using componentWillReceiveProps() and static getDerivedStateFromProps() but again couldn't get rerenders to trigger.

Hosted on Zeit: https://starwars-search-nm7mk0268.now.sh/

Comment: I ended up refactoring all of the logic to the parent component and just returning the value of all the logic.

This allowed me to get away from nested ternarys and clean up this component's render method.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up refactoring all of the logic to the parent component and just returning the value of all the logic. This allowed me to get away from nested ternarys and clean up this component's render method